# Agreement in "tu m'as quittée"

Tags: accord, participe-passé

In the song "[Tu es partout](https://archive.org/details/EdithPiaf-TuEsPartoutsavingPrivateRyan)", [*Édith Piaf*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89dith_Piaf) sings

> Nous nous aimions bien tendrement
>   Comme s'aiment tous les amants
>   Et puis un jour **tu m'as quittée**
>   Depuis je suis désespérée

Evidently, "tu" applies to a man, so why is "quittée" in the feminine form? I believe I saw this usage several times, is it just an error?

Comment: Welcome to every french-speaking schoolkid's worst nightmare, the dreaded... « **accord du participe passé avec l'auxiliaire *avoir* !** » \*dramatic thunder strike\*

Comment: @RomainVALERI And then it gets worse: « accord du participe passé, le retour : les verbes pronominaux »

Comment: I never will understand why this is so much of a trouble for so many french-speaking people. The rule is quite easy to apply in most cases, while I agree some very complicated sentences make it difficult to find the direct object)... As a side remark, there's nothing in the text implying "tu" is a man other than the (historical) context and extrapolation. "Tu m'as quittée" could refer to a woman...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the auxiliary used to form the past tense is *avoir*, the past participle agreement is done with the direct object (provided that it appears before the verb, otherwise no agreement is done). In this sentence *tu* is the subject. The object is *me*, which refers to a woman, and therefore the past participle is correctly written *quittée*.

Comment: Just adding that "*m'*" is "*me*" abbreviated before vowel