# What is the tense in "j'avais vue deux heures plus tôt"?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, accord, participe-passé, temps-composés

> Le soir suivant, je voulus faire la même épreuve. Je fermai donc ma porte à clef pour être certain que personne ne pourrait pénétrer chez moi. Je m'endormis et je me réveillai comme chaque nuit. *On avait bu toute l'eau que j'**avais vue** deux heures plus tôt.*

I don't understand the tense in the very last clause "j'**avais vue** deux heures plus tôt". Is "vue" a typo and thus it should be "vu"? My dictionary shows

[image]

Comment: The same answer than the one to  [this other question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/22795/358) could be provided.  Is it enough for you or do you need a more elaborate answer? So, no typo, and it is the plus-que-parfait. Vu**e** has an **e** because of the past participle aggreement rule described [here](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14262/358). It just happens that in French *eau* is feminine.

Comment: @Laure: Thank you very much! It is very clear now. I would accept your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the rules of past participles agreement.

Verbs take either *avoir* or *être* as an *auxiliaire* when conjugated in *passé composé*, *plus-que-parfait* or any other composed tense. I'll use the *passé composé* for my examples:

> Manger (to eat) → Je mange (I eat/I'm eating) → J'ai mangé (I ate/I have eaten)
>
> Tomber (to fall) → Je tombe (I fall/I'm falling) → Je suis tombé (I fell/I have fallen)

The past participle agrees with the subject only if the *auxiliaire* is *être*:

> J'ai mangé. (male or female speaking)
>
> Je suis tombé. (male speaking)
>
> Je suis tombée. (female speaking)

So *voir* takes *avoir* as an *auxiliaire* (*j'ai vu*), hence your dictionary example.

Now, why *vue*? This is the main rule: if the *complément d'objet direct* is before the verb, then the past participle agrees with it (not with the subject), even if it's the *auxiliaire avoir*:

> J'ai mangé des pommes.
>
> Les pommes que j'ai mangées.
>
> Les pommes ? Je les ai mangées.

In your case, *vue* agrees with *l'eau* (feminine):

> J'avais vu l'eau.
>
> L'eau que j'avais vue.

---

**Now, there are many other rules, and some of them are really, really tricky.**