# Why do we add an "e" at the end of some verbs?

Tags: verbes, accord

Today in class the teacher wrote "Paris est la plus belle ville que j'aie jamais visitée". I was puzzled by why he added a "e" at the end of *visité*. From what I know, the sentence says *Paris is the most beautiful city I have ever visited*. He used *belle* instead of *beau* because *ville* is feminine, and he used the *subjonctif passé* after *que* because the sentence is subjective.

Please correct me if I'm wrong about anything. So my question is, why did he add an extra *e* at the end of the sentence? Is it because the subject (ville) is feminine or is it a direct object?

Comment: *Visitée* (past participle) agrees with *ville* (exactly with direct object pronoun *que* standing for *ville*). See [this answer](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/14262/358), and [this other one](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8386/accord-du-participe-les-plats-que-jai-cuisin%c3%a9s), and on http://linguistics.stackexchange.com : [Is this natural: gender concord of direct objects with the past participle in French?](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/9941/637).

Comment: Some great answers linked there. Definitely do read them, but to give a quick summary: If the direct object of a verb in the past participle appears before the verb, the verb agrees with it in gender (add "e" if feminine) and number (add "s" if plural).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the time line :
if you know what we are talking about when the verb appears, set gender and plural. 
If you don't know leave unchanged :

J'ai visité (we don't know yet what it is) la ville...les monuments..
La ville que (we know what it is) j'ai visitée... que j'ai vue
Les monuments que j'ai visités... que j'ai vus..

Sometime you know what but anticipate the description by le la les :

Je les ai vus, les monuments. 
Je l'ai visitée, la ville.

Comment: This advice doesn't work all the time. "J'ai rencontré les filles et je leur ai parlé". " J'ai rencontré les filles et je les ai saluées". Distinguishing direct & indirect object is essential.